# Scrollview Viewport Mask not hiding content

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollview

Here is a screenshot of my scene:

[image: scene]

I'd like to have a grid of prefabs which I can scroll through. The grid works and the scrolling works, but the mask on the viewport does not hide the content. I've tried selecting/deselecting the "Show Mask Graphic" option, I've tried using a `Rect Mask 2D` instead *and* in addition, and I've tried putting mask components on the `ScrollView` itself. I'm at a bit of a loss for what to do.

How can I prevent the content from appearing if it is not within the viewport? Here are some screenshots of the scene objects' inspector properties:

`ScrollView`:

[image: ScrollView]

`ViewPort`:

[image: ViewPort]

`Content`:

[image: Content]

GameObject Prefab:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Because those are `Sprite`s, not `UI.Image`s

The Unity UI Mask object can only mask other UI elements. [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) is not one of those. You should change your prefab to have an [`UI.Image` component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s, this was really useful and helped me quite a bit. So if I do need my objects to be sprites, is there no way to have the behaviour I want with the mask?

Comment: @Rookatu Nope, if they *have* to be sprites, there's no way to mask them with a UI Mask. There *might* be some shader trickery you could do, but I doubt it.

Comment: Okay, seems like an unfortunate limitation but thanks again for the helpful answer!